# How do you force a canvas refresh in Javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, refresh

In the code that follows the function board repaints the canvas. However the canvas is not repainted until control reverts to the user. What code sequence is required to force a refresh whenever the function is invoked?

```
function doRound (ctx, game, loc, move){ // move is selected human move
    let go = move;
    let translate = {0:-1,1:-8,2:1,3:8}
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        loc = loc+translate[go]; // calculate move
        if (illegal(loc)){
            let text = (i === 0) ? "You lose!" : "You win!";
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = text;
            break;  // game over
        }       
        game[loc] = true; // place move on board
        board(ctx);  // refresh canvas
        if (i === 0){go = compMove()};  // calc computer move
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to wipe off your canvas before redrawing all its previous content.

you can do so by using clearRect() and pass it the size of the canvas :

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

here is a basic example on how this can be useful

```js
//note in javascript if an html element has an id a variable with the same name exists you can ommit to get it with document.getElementById("mycan");
let ctx=mycan.getContext("2d");
//initial rect position in x
let move = 20;

//does some heavy processing for no reason
const heavyProcessing = (arr)=>{
  for(let i = 0;i<1000000;i++) 
    {arr.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+1)}
};

//adding an eventListener who listens to user input
window.addEventListener("keydown",(e)=>{
//if(e.key=="ArrowRight){move++} increments x position of red square if the user presses the right arrow on his keyboard
  move+=(e.key=="ArrowRight"); 
  });

//call to heavyProcessing before animation begins
let ar=[];
heavyProcessing(ar);

//simple animation timer
setInterval(()=>{
  //wipe off canvas before each redraw
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,mycan.width,mycan.height);
  //choose next rectangle color before drawing
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  //drawing a rectangle
  ctx.fillRect(move,20,50,50);
  //recalls the code above every frame at a rate of 60 per second
},1000/60)
```

```html
<canvas id = "mycan" width=300 height=200>
</canvas>
```

Comment: That is useful, but what if there is some heavy processing going on? GivenJS is single-threaded, how do you force an interrupt to refresh the screen at the required interval?

Comment: Heavy processing would mean you get some value which in terms allows you to store those values, here all i'm doing is redrawing something. If you have for instance a sorting algorithm that sorts an array of à million items. You would store this sorted array somewhere and not recall the sorting function each time.
Javascript is not single-threaded, have a look at :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: I'm struggling to know where to add setInterval(). Should it be in the code sequence I provided, in the calling code where the user enters their move, or in the compMove() function. compMove() typically takes 2 or 3 seconds to come up with the computer move, and during that time the user's move is not displayed, even though board() explicitly refreshes the canvas (although nothing happens until after the computer move and control reverts to the user for their next move)..

Comment: doRound does not have to be called each frame, you would use a click(or keypress) eventListener to detect if a click has been made. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp
But if this code takes 3 seconds you might have some other performance issues, Look if you're not loading any images in the setInterval, if you do not have console.log in for loop that goes over 100 items, if you don't log big objects in the console. If you sort huge arrays etc ...
I've updated the code to show an example of eventListener use

Comment: Thanks for your time on this. I think i get it. The reason for the heavy processing is that the computer tries to explore different options. With three moves there are potentially 3**64 moves, all to figure out which of the three is best! I'd like to try and push the exponent as far as I can to figure out if it makes a big difference or not. The game is at https://basilisk.net